# JTW singlesign on not generating key correctly

Tags: php, jwt, single-sign-on

i'm using tribe application - https://tribe.so and I am trying to integrate it into my current website. it uses JWT for generating a SSO key, and their documentation says i need to generate a SSO token and then redirect the user to their authentication site which will then sign them in and redirect them to my dashboard for my current website.

```
    use JWT;

const privateKey = '{Your Private Key}';

function createToken() {
  $userData = [
    'email' => $user['email'],
    'sub' => $user['id'],
    'name' => $user['name'],
  ];
  return JWT::encode($userData, privateKey, 'HS256');
}
```

I have integrated the above code to my login script, but i am unsure on how to return the actual single sign on key in my redirect script below.

```
    $ssokey = createToken();
    header("Location: https://inoneplace.tribe.so/auth/sso?ssoToken=$ssokey");
```

I have tried reading forum posts, but im not getting anywhere!

Any help & advice would be great

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to ask here. Can you point to that documentation you mentioned?

Comment: https://developers.tribe.so/docs/jwt-sso

Comment: I don’t get what exactly the question is now. Their example has an additional `&redirect=/answers` at the end of that address, presumably to let the system know where you want to redirect the user to, after they are signed in, but other than that, I don’t see what is missing?

Comment: Basically, the code i've added above, it doesn't seem to be generating the $ssokey so i'm not sure if the $ssokey = createToken(); is correctly used